# How do I speed up C++ execution with in-line functions?

Tags: c++, class

I am transferring a FORTRAN Monte Carlo program to C++ and found that when completely transferred the C++ program runs nearly twice as slow as the FORTRAN program.  I am trying to draft a 2nd version of the C++ program where many of the functions are brought in line through the use of class structures to speed things up; however, some of the functions are upwards of 40 or 50 lines and I have read that bringing large functions in line can slow down the program.  What is too large when it comes to bringing functions in line and how can I speed up a C++ program (without multi processing) such that a C++ program can execute as fast, or near as fast as a FORTRAN program?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the results of running a profiler on your program.

Comment: Are you sure the overhead is due to function calls?

Comment: Have you used any sort of profiling tool to first see where exactly the bottlenecks are?

Comment: Entire books, and SO tags ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance ), have been written about performance. We can't answer what can be done to optimize the performance of a C++ program in a single answer. But assuming that the overhead is due to function calls is not justified in any way.

Comment: I recommend profiling your code to find where the execution time is spent.  If you can narrow down the cause of Fortran-to-C++ slowdown to a _small_ example, then that could make a useful StackOverflow question (or the process might help you figure out the answer on your own).

Comment: Since FORTRAN is already optimized I have never had to use a profiling tool or to be honest have never even heard of one.  Where can I find a profiling tool with documentation that describes how to use it?

Comment: @Jon Profiling tool somewhat depends on what compiler and OS you use.  If you use `gfortran` to compile, then `gprof` is a simple and useful command-line profiling tool.  See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/

Comment: @Jon Not only the _language_ can be optimized or not; also your _algorithms_. I've been a C++ developer for 10+ years now and I've produced a number of optimizations, and all of them were about the algorithms used, not the language itself. A profiler is a key tool for identifying that. You can use one or not, it's your choice, but it's the first step you must take in order to optimize your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inlining in C++ is only a suggestion to the compiler.  If the function is too complicated, it will not be inlined by most modern compilers.  The compiler will do what it can to optimize the calls in any case, even without the "inline" keyword, so long as the implementation is available when it's being compiled.  There are also compilers that will inline across compilation units, but this is less common.

In any case, it's unlikely that function calls are dominating your processing time.  You probably want to profile your code to figure out where the bottleneck is actually at before putting too much effort into micro-optimizations that the compiler is probably doing for you in any case.

Comment: Let me ask the question in a differnt way.  I am used to FORTRAN where the compiler is already optimized for efficiency and speed, so many of the comments being made here are unfamilear to me.  What other factors can cause the code to run slower and what tools can I use to determine which ones are most responsible.  I have never used a profiling tool and as a result I do not know where to obtain one, any suggestions as where to find one with documentation on how to use it would be greatly appreceated.

Comment: What environment are you in?  Linux? Windows? OSX?  And C++ is also optimized for efficiency and speed.  Chances are some library that you're using is not as fast as it is in Fortran.

Comment: I am using OSX with XCode; however, most of my programming is by command line and i must admit that as of yet I am not intimitely familiar with all the bells and whistles on XCode, but I am going to change that in the very near future.

Comment: You could do worse than googling "XCode profiler."   Here's a start: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html